# MySQL query that needs a lot of (complex?) filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database table (People):

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  Name  |   Age  |  Time  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Tim    |   30   |  10:10 |
| Jill   |   31   |  10:20 |
| Peter  |   31   |  10:30 |
| Peter  |   33   |  10:40 |
| Jack   |   32   |  10:50 |
| Susan  |   35   |  10:60 |
| Susan  |   35   |  11:70 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now I want to get 5 names which are the oldest from this list:

```
Select * FROM People ORDER BY Age DESC LIMIT 5
```

This will give:

```
| Susan  |   35   |  11:70 |
| Susan  |   35   |  10:60 |
| Peter  |   33   |  10:40 |
| Jack   |   32   |  10:50 |
| Peter  |   31   |  10:30 |
```

Now this is not exactly what I want. We see Susan in there twice, same as Peter. I don't want duplicate names to show up. Now we see that the 2 Susans have both the same age, so the Susan with the highest time `(mm:ss)` should be filter out (in this case: `| Susan  |   35   |  11:70 |`)

Fot the 2 Peters we see that one Peter is older, so in this case the younger Peter should be filtered out (`| Peter  |   31   |  10:30 |`)

So how would this Query look like? It should first select all, then order them by Age (oldest on top), then filter out the duplicate names where it must first look at the age (lowest gets filtered) and then at the time (highest time gets filter out) and then DESC LIMIT 5.

So the only correct result will look like this:

```
| Susan  |   35   |  10:60 |
| Peter  |   33   |  10:40 |
| Jack   |   32   |  10:50 |
| Jill   |   31   |  10:20 |
| Peter  |   31   |  10:30 |
```

Comment: so u want us to write the query?

Comment: Did you mean to have Peter show up twice in the final result?

Comment: Read up on the use of 'UNIQUE" in the query.

Comment: @PeteWilson, do you mean `DISTINCT`? Either way, it isn't quite what he's looking for. That would return all of the results, since the resulting rows are, in fact, distinct form each other (due to `Time` or `Age` being different). `GROUP BY` is more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Name, Age, MIN(Time) As LowestTime
FROM
    People
GROUP BY 
    Name, Age
ORDER BY
    Age DESC, Name ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Just beat me to it! Though it should probably be `min(time)`.

Comment: While this *does* work, the OP stated he did not want duplicate names (even if his result set doesn't match what he said). Also, if additional columns are added, they will not be retrieved correctly (as MIN/MAX does not change the values of the other columns at all, only the column with MIN/MAX applied).

Comment: @bfrohs: Maurice's example at the end of his answer lists two different Peters with two different ages but only the one Susan with the minimum time. `MIN(Time)` together with `GROUP BY Name, Age` eliminates persons with the same name and age, but different times.

Comment: This seems to work great, didn't know MIN(Time) was possible!! Thank you very much, also to all others contributing!

Comment: Yes, unless you want to have persons with the same age be sorted by name.

Comment: @Maurice, be aware that `MIN()` does not take into account any other columns (it only finds the minimum value for that specific column in the grouped rows, but the other columns return the same result as if `MIN()` had not been used). Ergo, if you end up adding another column, you may not receive the result you're expecting. Just a heads up :)

Comment: @Oliver, yes but in this case less time is better so he needs to be above the person with the same age but more time

Comment: @bfrohs thanks but for the moment it seems to work as intended, perhaps I'll do another evaluation when more people are added in the table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name,Age,Max(Time) as Time
FROM People
GROUP BY concat(Age,':',Name)
ORDER BY Age DESC,Time ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

The GROUP BY takes care of Susan, the ORDER BY of Peter

Comment: "I don't want duplicate names to show up." ... "Susan with the highest time" ... "the younger Peter". Your query returns duplicate Peters, and the Susan with the lowest time. It also does not retrieve the 5 most recent, but rather the 5 oldest (age), ordered by Time.

Comment: In your example as the "only correct result" you have 2 Peters - so I understood you want duplicate names, if they are of different age. As for the "wrong susan", I fixed my error. Concerning the sort: Your "only correct result" is sorted by Age, so I did the same. I changed the sort order on the time, as I didn't realise that "10:20" is newer than "10:30"

Comment: Your query now returns the correct Susan, but it is still ordered incorrectly (sorted by `Age`, rather than `Time`). And yeah, the OP did make it confusing with that example result set. I asked if it was meant to look like that, but still no reply.

Comment: Sorting by Age is exactly what the "only correct result" requires.

Comment: "Now I want to get 5 names which are the oldest from this list:". But I guess this is the difference between going by what he says, or by the result set he typed in. Just my opinion, I guess :P

Comment: Wait, no, you're right. I misread. He means oldest by `Age`. My bad.

Comment: OK, again: I targeted the "only correct result", and this is my solution. Feel free to post your own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this query is what you're looking for. It filters by Name:Age, then Name:Time, and finally does a final group by Name and `ORDER` as necessary.

**Query**

```
SELECT `Name`, `Age`, `Time`
FROM `People`
WHERE concat(`Name`,'-',`Time`)
 IN (
  SELECT concat(`Name`,'-',MAX(`Time`))
  FROM `People`
  WHERE concat(`Name`,'-',`Age`)
  IN (
   SELECT concat(`Name`,'-',MIN(`Age`))
   FROM `People`
   GROUP BY `Name`
  )
  GROUP BY `Name`
 )
 GROUP BY `Name`
 ORDER BY `Age` DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

**Note:** *While this is a valid query and returns the results you're looking for, it can get pretty expensive, especially with a larger table. If you plan to do this filtering on a larger table, I would suggest adding a column where you concatenate these fields manually, and set up an index against both columns. Also, I'm assuming this was just a quick example, but if you should also have an `id` column set up that is `PRIMARY` and `auto_increment`.*

Comment: syntax error. you cannot group by Name when selecting all columns in select.

Comment: Ha, sorry, don't usually use the `*`, so wasn't aware of that issue. Try it now :)

Comment: @emaillenin, I've fixed the query and tested. It now returns the 5 most recent results (by `Time`), with no duplicate names, youngest by `Age`, and most recent by `Time`.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, it's not a simple filter? If the OP was using PHP or another scripting language as well, sure, this would be easy and could be filtered as queried, or with multiple queries, but with only a query to work with, this is the only one that gets the exact results wanted by the OP.